# VB.NET - How to add element1 to element2 and add sum of element1 and 2 with element 3 in an array

Tags: vb.net

I can't quite explain it, but this is what I'm trying to do.

```
Array1 = {1, 5, 7, 4}

0+1 = 1
1+5 = 6
6+7 = 13
13+4 = 17

Array2 = {1, 6, 13, 17}
```

I still cant figure out how to write the code.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you loop through each value in the array?

Comment: The fact that you can't explain it is part of the problem. You haven't given the problem enough thought yet. You're expecting to be able to write code when you don't know what that code has to do, which obviously isn't happening. You should start solving any programming problem by forgetting that it's a programming problem. How would you do it manually, with pen and paper? What are the steps you performed to accomplish that? Formalise those steps into an algorithm. Finally, write code to implement the algorithm. If you don't have an algorithm, you don't have a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay my bad, I was just being stupid. I found the solution to my answer and it turned out to be something really simple.
Thanks to the folks in the comment section.

```
Dim Array1 As Integer() = {1, 5, 7, 4}
Dim Array2 As Integer() = {0}
For i As Integer = 0 To Array1.Length - 1

'.Add() isnt real, so i made an extension
Array2.Add(Array2(i) + Array1(i))
Next

'to remove the 0 at the start
Array2 = Array2.Skip(1).ToArray
```

Honestly, I don't know how this did not arrive in my head.